# EasyPHP Webserver - Dashboard - http://127.0.0.1:10000 No longer loading

Tags: webserver, easyphp

I am running `EasyPHP Webserver 14.1` on `Win Server 2012`.

When I first installed it the dashboard loaded fine.

Now that I have built up my `PHPbb3` forum it no longer loads. The browser continuously states

> Waiting for response from 172.0.0.1...

but nothing happens, it just keeps spinning trying to load.

**Is there any way I can fix /restore / reinstall the dashboard without affecting any work I've done on `PHPbb3`?**

---

If it helps after some searching on this forum I created a `.bat` file containing:

```
ews-dashboard.exe -S 127.0.0.1:10000 -c ews-dashboard.ini cmd /k
```

This opens a CMD window containing the following:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Webserver-14.1b2\dashboard>ews-dashboard.exe -S 127.0.0.1:10000 -c ews-dashboard.ini
>   PHP 5.4.30 Development Server started at Tue Nov 14 14:33:33 2017
>   Listening on http://127.0.0.1:10000
>   Document root is C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Webserver-14.1b2\dashboard
>   Press Ctrl-C to quit.

But this doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Must be a bug...Tried stopping services and running EasyPHP-Webserver-14.1b2 setup again. It worked and the dashboard loaded fine.... then later it refused to load once more. Another run of setup didn't work this time :(

Answer (score 0):

it will work if you change the current port.

`start-ews.bat`

```
ews-dashboard.exe -S 127.0.0.1:1000 -c ews-dashboard.ini cmd /k
```

---

`ews-dashboard.ini`

```
[ServiceEx]

ServiceExeFullPath = "D:/Program Files/EasyPHP-Webserver\dashboard\ews-dashboard.exe" 


; program arguments to be sent to executable
options = "-S 127.0.0.1:1000"


; can program interact with desktop [true | false] (default: true)

desktop = false


; start type (valid values: Auto Manual Disabled) (default: auto)

Start=Auto


; start the service upon installation [true | false] (default: no) 

StartNow=true
```